# AX 2012 Form with Query shows empty line when now record is found

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a Form with a Query, the records are shown in a Grid.
When the query returns no result an empty line is shown, when the user presses F5 to refresh it shows the expected "grid is empty" message.

What can I do to get the expected "grid is empty" message without pressing F5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the form data source, set the property `InsertIfEmpty=No`

[image]